# WordPress redirects to login page when I enter url.com/index.php

Tags: pages, redirect, login

WordPress redirects to login page when I enter `url.com/index.php` or just `http://url.com`. When I enter with https the opens normally. Please help.

Comment: can you please explain  in details

Comment: Redirect your site to HTTP to HTTPs it will solve your problem.

Comment: Welcome to WPSE. You may need to provide additional details in your question so that people know a little more about your configuration/setup and don't have to guess.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to fix your issue.

1. **Add Codes to wp-config.php**

   Add these lines in wp-config.php file:

   ```
   define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
   define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
   ```
2. **Clear Cache**

   Make sure to clear the cache from your browser, as well as cache
   plugins.  You can also try adding this line to wp-config.php file:

   ```
   define( 'WP_CACHE', false );
   ```
3. **Identify the Defective Plugins**

   May be, you are using a defective plugin that is causing the issue.
   Try deactivating all the plugins in your site. Then activate one by
   one to find the defective one.